# Twos complement arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic

If I have the expression:

```
 1011 0000 1110
-1000 1110 0001
----------------
```

Then, I find the twos complement of the second number:

```
 0111 0001 1110
+0000 0000 0001
---------------
 0111 0000 1111
```

I then add this to the first number:

```
 1011 0000 1110
+0111 0000 1111
---------------
 0010 0001 1101
```

But the answer given is:

```
 0010 0001 1100
```

Can anybody see my error?

Comment: I don't see how this is a computer science question.

Comment: @Raphael, it's part of my Digital System Architecture module on my BEng Electronic Engineering course. I'm not sure if it counts as a CS question; I just assumed anybody that studies CS might be able to give me a hand.

Comment: @Raphael, in hindsight, perhaps the Electrical Engineering forum is the place for it.

Comment: Neither, imho. When it comes down to it, you are asking, "how to add two numbers?". Granted, twos complement is not the encoding we learn in elementary school, but the scope/difficulty of the task is the same as back then. Being able to do so is a *tool* but neither (part of) what computer *science* or electrical *engineering* is about.

Answer (score 1):

The given answer can't be correct: Just from the last digits it claims that the result of subtracting an odd number from an even number is even.

However, you also made a mistake in your calculation: The 2's complement should be `0111 0001 1111`.